# Error al querer importar en python

Tags: python

Hola tengo el error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usuarios' que puedo hace para solucionarlo ya que realmente si existe usuarios.

```
from usuarios import conexion

connect = conexion.conectar()
database = connect[0]
cursor = connect[1]


class Nota:

    def __init__(self, usuario_id, titulo, descripcion):
        self.usuario_id = usuario_id
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.descripcion = descripcion

    def guardar(self):
        sql = "INSERT INTO notas VALUES(null, %s, %s, %s, NOW())"
        nota = (self.usuario_id, self.titulo, self.descripcion)

        cursor.execute(sql, nota)
        database.commit()
        return [cursor.rowcount, self]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que es usuarios? Un modulo que instalaste? Si no es el caso, donde está el archivo .py que tratas de importar?

Comment: Según como está importado el módulo, debe haber un archivo **usuarios.py** paralelo al archivo del script que muestras. Ese archivo debe tener una class llamada `conexion` con un método `conectar`

Comment: @DanteS. acabo de editar a la pregunta y ahi aparece de donde lo saque

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usuarios'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/502579/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-usuarios)

Comment: @ChemaCortes La probe y no me funciona aunque este en pycharm.